# How to query without any line breaks within fields and records in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 fields, `"FieldA", "FieldB", and "FieldC"` that contain line breaks within the field themselves that when output into a csv that contains values like:

```
"This is some
sample text that is listed here"
```

What query or means can I use to query on those fields to get the value while removing any of these line breaks?

```
set echo off
set verify off
set termout on
set heading off
set feedback off
set newpage none
set recsep off

spool "data.txt"
SELECT
LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(c, CHR(10), ''),CHR(13),''))) 
FROM
mytable;
spool off;
```

The current output is:

```
 valueC1




 valueC2





valueC3
```

All the gaps apparently are all "spaces". How do I get rid of these? I am guessing they are trailing spaces? Trying:

```
RTRIM(replace(C,Chr(10),''))
```

Appears to have the same output. There must be some kind of strange ghost character i cant see? When I select a column that did not have any weird spaces, then there are no extra spaces in the file generated.

Comment: `replace(str,chr(10),null)` you can use the ascii value for line break which is 10.

Comment: There appears to be a ton of trailing spaces at the end that is causing big gaps to show between my data...

Comment: Check for CHR(9) - Tab as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SELECT REPLACE(FieldA, CHR(10), ' ') FROM YourTable

Comment: The issue is now even though I have removed all spaces, between each record/field there are a lot of extra spaces between each record. Have no idea where they are coming from.

Comment: Did you try LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(FieldA, CHR(10), ' ')))

Comment: Just tried it, updated original post. Looks like when I select only fields that do not have these "extra spaces/breaks", then the output does not have extra spaces, but even just selecting a single column "C" that has these spaces/linebreaks/ghost characters, theres about 4 line breaks between each record...

Comment: Does this help ? LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(FieldA, CHR(10), ''),CHR(13),''),CHR(9), '')))

Comment: Just tried it and the same breaks in my OP are still there, arrowing through the gaps appears to all be spaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55789/discussion-between-tmnt2014-and-setsuna).

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`REPLACE(FieldA, CHR(10), ' ')`